# Why is this reaction spontaneous in standard conditions?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, free-energy

To study if this reaction is spontaneous I proceed in this way:
$$\ce{2H_{3}O^{+} +Fe ->H_{2} +Fe^{2+} + 2H_{2}O}$$
First I write the two semireaction:
$$reduction: \ \ \ce{2H_{3}O^{+} +2e^{-} -> H_{2}} $$
$$oxidation: \ \ \ce{Fe -> 2e^{-} +Fe^{+}} $$
Then I write the scheme of the cell:
$$\ce{Fe|Fe^{2+}||H_{3}O^{+}|H_{2}}$$
I know that:
$$E^{0}_{cell}=E^{0}_{right}-E^{0}_{left}$$
$$E^{0}_{cell}=E^{0}_{H_{3}O^{+}|H_{2}}-E^{0}_{Fe|Fe^{2+}}=-E^{0}_{Fe|Fe^{2+}}=-0.44$$
But also:
$$\Delta G^{0}=-nFE^{0}_{cell}$$
So $$\Delta G^{0}>0$$
And the reaction is not spontaneous, while my textbook says it is, so I must be wrong. Someone could find my error?

Comment: Note that it is preferred not to use MarhJax/Latex formatting of titles on Chemistry SE site to avoid search problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while since I took electrochemistry so I'm not sure about the formal procedure that you're using.

You wrote the correct overall reaction.

$$\ce{2H3O+ + Fe -> H2 + Fe^{2+} +2H2O}\tag{1}$$

and you almost wrote the correct half cells reactions (should be $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ in equation 3):

$$reduction:  \ \ \ce{2H3O+ + 2e− ->H2}\tag{2}$$

$$oxidation: \ \ \ce{Fe -> 2e^{-} +Fe^{2+}}\tag{3} $$ 
Then you wrote the scheme of the cell: $$\ce{Fe|Fe^{2+}||H_{3}O^{+}|H_{2}}\tag{4}$$ And an equation for the overall cell potential. 
$$E^{0}_{cell}=E^{0}_{right}-E^{0}_{left}\tag{5}$$

Your problem is between equations 4 and 5. To subtract $E^{0}_{left}$ the potential must be written as the reduction potential for the half cell. So either you're supposed to be:

- Adding the values for the right and left reactions in equation 5

-- or--

- Writing both half cells as reduction potentials in equation 4.

---

The gist here is that the tabular values are always written as *reduction* potentials. So for iron:

$$\ce{2e^{-} +Fe^{2+} -> Fe }\quad\quad E^{0}_{red} = -0.44\tag{6} $$

I was taught to reverse the sign for an oxidation reaction.

$$\ce{Fe -> 2e^{-} +Fe^{2+}}\quad\quad E^{0}_{ox} = 0.44\tag{7} $$

Then add the reduction and oxidation potentials to get the overall cell potential.

$$E^{0}_{cell}=E^{0}_{red} + E^{0}_{ox}\tag{8}$$

Answer (score 3):

The main mistake is rather **algebraic** and forgetting the electrochemical conventions. When we write this equation, we follow the convention that all electrode potential values will be inserted *right from the table with their signs intact*, whether it is an oxidation or reduction. Don't change the sign of the electrode potential value. The sign of the electrode potential is **invariant**.

$$E^{0}_{cell}=E^{0}_{right}-E^{0}_{left}$$

So from the table, the Fe(II)/Fe(0) couple is -0.44 V

So, $$E^{0}_{cell}=0.00-(-0.44)= +0.44V $$

when $E^{0}_{cell}$ is positive, delta G value is negative.

Comment: I do believe that this is the way that is used in current teaching. The "improvement" is to get the sign change, $-(-0.44)$ on paper rather than doing it mentally.

Comment: In old school teaching, the equation was E0cell=E0right+E0left, and the student was asked to change the sign. This was the Gibb's or American convention. Rest of the Europe followed Ostwald's approach, which is taught today.

Comment: LOL - My first chemistry class was in 1968 when I was in the 10th grade. "Old school" enough?

Comment: That is exactly the time I was talking about. Glad that you saw the golden era of science in the US.

Answer (score -4):

Your mistake is that $E^\circ_\ce{Fe/Fe^{2+}} = \pu{-0.44 V}.$ So that $-E^\circ_\ce{Fe/Fe^{2+}} = \pu{+0.44 V}.$

Comment: no... $ E°_{Fe^{2+}/Fe}$ = - $0.44$ V. The table values are always written as reductions.